# How to match xml layout files to integers on an decompiled apk?

Tags: android, decompiling, decompiler, apktool

I am trying to learn how decompiling an android apk using apktool works. When I use apktool to extract a simple apk, all of the resources are extracted correctly. When I check the activity `onCreate`, I expect to see `findViewById(myview)` but I get this:

```
findViewById(2356778)
```

I do not know where this number comes from, and I can not figure out this number refers to which XML layout file.

Comment: The number is actually resource file id so in reverse engg it will showing like you as numbers.

Comment: Do you know about the generated R class and how it's used to index Android resources?

Comment: That is because each `view` is assigned an `id` that is of type `int`. So the number that you see is the `int` value of an `id` of some `view`. This mapping is stored in the generated `R.java` file. Search for the `int` to understand the view `id`

Answer (score 0):

If you extracted with the Apktool means,
Your corresponding layout name for `findViewById(0x7f030028)` will be present in `/res/values/public.xml`

In `public.xml` you can see like this,

```
<public type="layout" name="your_layout_name" id="0x7f030028" />
```